# How to use mongodb aggregation to transform document in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My document looks like as shown below and I want to transform it using aggregation. Inside favourite_products I have product array and it has product_id corresponding to each shops. Now I just want product ids of all shops but sorted based on time. :

```
"favourite_products": [
                {
                    "shop": {
                        "shop_id": "59465888f7babb000485574b",
                        "time": "2017-07-12T06:11:19.817Z"
                    },
                    "product": [
                        {
                            "product_id": "594c2d56f7afcf00043b1195",
                            "time": "2017-07-12T06:10:36.775Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "product_id": "594ac36c76de720004e819f6",
                            "time": "2017-07-12T06:11:19.817Z"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "shop": {
                        "shop_id": "593acc24a2902d0004211f1f",
                        "time": "2017-07-12T06:12:59.372Z"
                    },
                    "product": [
                        {
                            "product_id": "594ac36c76de720004e819f6",
                            "time": "2017-07-12T06:12:59.372Z"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
"favourite_products"

 ["59465888f7babb000485574b",594c2d56f7afcf00043b1195","594ac36c76de720004e819f6","593acc24a2902d0004211f1f","594ac36c76de720004e819f6"]
```

Comment: Why would you want both shop and product id's in the same output array? Also note that your output example is not actually sorted by time.

Comment: What you did to achieve this. Show your code and ask your problem. this is not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes I want output ids to be time sorted. And above I just showed how my final document will look like, Pls consider it as if it time sorted. And I have put  shop and product id's in the same array bcs shop id correspond to one shop and product ids correspond to products related to that shop which are favourite.

Comment: I really don't think you should use the aggregation framework for this at all. You simply are not "aggregating" anything, and there is no way to "sort" an array without using `$unwind`, and that is something you need to avoid if this really is just output "per document". It's a task better suited to client side code instead. And by "client" that means the application client to the database, as opposed to the "browser" or other eventual client. It's very easy to transform data per document without resorting to the aggregation framework.

Comment: @NeilLunn I actually want to extract product ids from one document and then fetch products corresponding to those ids as json response. So can you tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below returns time ordered documents of favourite_products.product.product_id

use project if you want the result as different documents.
or use group if you want the result as the array in one document.

```
db['testing-aggregate'].aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$favourite_products'},
    {$unwind:'$favourite_products.product'},
    {$sort:{'favourite_products.product.time':1}}, // order by time. 1=ascending | -1=descending 
    //  {$project:{
    //      '_id':0, // exclude _id from output
    //      'favourite_products':'$favourite_products.product.product_id' // return only product_id
    //  }},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        product_id:{$push:'$favourite_products.product.product_id'}
    }}  
])
```

Comment: @Pav.k Actually favourite_products is a part of document , so I need to match or find that document corresponding to one userid. And then extract  products ids and sort by time from all shops in favourite_products array. And finally use product ids to fetch all products corresponding to those ids.

Comment: use $match{} to find the one you need.

if you searching on inner array, use:
{$match{'innerArray._id'='id'}},
{$unwind:'innerArray'} 
{$match{'innerArray._id'='id'}}

Comment: your answer is exactly what i wanted, it worked. But can you tell why we have _id=null

Comment: When using {$group}, you have to specify the key to group by (_id:'key').

From the mongo docs on $group(aggregation):
The _id field is mandatory; however, you can specify an _id value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.